# How can I run this command without the use of sudo?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, conky

I have been trying to find a way to display (AMD) GPU load in my conky, and while researching methods to display load, I found a command that - while requiring sudo - worked to print the GPU load to the terminal (`sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/64/amdgpu_pm_info`). Conky cannot run sudo commands, so I attempted to both:

1. use visudo to allow myself access to the `/sys/kernel/debug/dri/64` folder without having to enter the sudo password, and
2. use chown to modify the permissions of the file to a+rwx.

Neither of these methods seemed to work to allow me to use the command without entering the sudo password, however.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a question, why do  you use `sudo` in the first place ? What does `stat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/64/amdgpu_pm_info` tells you ?

Comment: @Serg `stat: cannot stat '/sys/kernel/debug/dri/64/amdgpu_pm_info': Permission denied`

Comment: Also, how exactly did you modify `sudeors`?

Comment: @muru, I added the line `%username% ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sys/kernel/debug/dri/64` (and a variant in which `amdgpu_pm_info` was appended to the end of that line) with no change -- still prompted for a password.

Comment: Your `sudoers` line is incorrect in couple of aspects. One, the format is `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: command`. It's supposed to be for allowing **executing** a file. In your case, your goal is not executing a program file, but rather to read it.  I think we can make a simple workaround for your case, but I'll have to post it tomorrow. Late night here

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same, accessing this file from a shell script. Nothing works, even setting u+s permissions to the shell script. Only running the script itself with sudo works.

UPDATE:

I found this to work:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /sys/kernel/debug
```

You must do it exactly like this (incomplete path). Works for me.